# Delete commit from array Ruby gitlab

Tags: arrays, ruby, gitlab, rubygems

I am trying to remove one of the objects from a gitlab array of several commits.

```
[
    {
        :commit=>#<Git: :Object: :Commit:   @base=#<Git: :Base:    @logger=nil, @working_directory=#<Git: :WorkingDirectory:   @path=" ">, @repository=#<Git: :Repository:   @path=" /.git">, @index=#<Git: :Index:   @path=" /.git/index">, @lib=#<Git: :Lib:   @git_dir=" /.git", @git_index_file=" /.git/index", @git_work_dir=" ", @path=nil, @logger=nil, @git_system_env_variables={
            "GIT_DIR"=>nil,
            "GIT_WORK_TREE"=>nil,
            "GIT_INDEX_FILE"=>nil,
            "GIT_SSH"=>nil
        }>>, @objectish="", @contents=nil, @trees=nil, @size=nil, @sha="", @tree=#<Git: :Object: :Tree:    @base=#<Git: :Base:    @logger=nil, @working_directory=#<Git: :WorkingDirectory:   @path=" ">, @repository=#<Git: :Repository:   @path=" /.git">, @index=#<Git: :Index:   @path=" /.git/index">, @lib=#<Git: :Lib:   @git_dir=" /.git", @git_index_file=" /.git/index", @git_work_dir=" ", @path=nil, @logger=nil, @git_system_env_variables={
            "GIT_DIR"=>nil,
            "GIT_WORK_TREE"=>nil,
            "GIT_INDEX_FILE"=>nil,
            "GIT_SSH"=>nil
        }>>, @objectish="", @contents=nil, @trees=nil, @size=nil, @sha=nil, @mode=nil, @blobs=nil>, @parents=[#<Git: :Object: :Commit:    @base=#<Git: :Base:    @logger=nil, @working_directory=#<Git: :WorkingDirectory:   @path=" ">, @repository=#<Git: :Repository:   @path=" /.git">, @index=#<Git: :Index:   @path=" /.git/index">, @lib=#<Git: :Lib:   @git_dir=" /.git", @git_index_file=" /.git/index", @git_work_dir=" ", @path=nil, @logger=nil, @git_system_env_variables={
                "GIT_DIR"=>nil,
                "GIT_WORK_TREE"=>nil,
                "GIT_INDEX_FILE"=>nil,
                "GIT_SSH"=>nil
            }>>, @objectish="", @contents=nil, @trees=nil, @size=nil, @sha=nil, @tree=nil, @parents=nil, @author=nil, @committer=nil, @message=nil>
        ], @author=#<Git: :Author:   @name=" ", @email="", @date=2022-05-19 23: 02: 18 +0000>, @committer=#<Git: :Author:    @name=" ", @email=" ", @date=2022-05-19 23: 02: 18 +0000>, @message="test: test it">,
        :failed=>false
    },
    {
        :commit=>#<Git: :Object: :Commit:   @base=#<Git: :Base:    @logger=nil, @working_directory=#<Git: :WorkingDirectory:   @path=" ">, @repository=#<Git: :Repository:   @path=" /.git">, @index=#<Git: :Index:   @path=" /.git/index">, @lib=#<Git: :Lib:   @git_dir=" /.git", @git_index_file=" /.git/index", @git_work_dir=" ", @path=nil, @logger=nil, @git_system_env_variables={
            "GIT_DIR"=>nil,
            "GIT_WORK_TREE"=>nil,
            "GIT_INDEX_FILE"=>nil,
            "GIT_SSH"=>nil
        }>>, @objectish="", @contents=nil, @trees=nil, @size=nil, @sha="", @tree=#<Git: :Object: :Tree:    @base=#<Git: :Base:    @logger=nil, @working_directory=#<Git: :WorkingDirectory:   @path=" ">, @repository=#<Git: :Repository:   @path=" /.git">, @index=#<Git: :Index:   @path=" /.git/index">, @lib=#<Git: :Lib:   @git_dir=" /.git", @git_index_file=" /.git/index", @git_work_dir=" ", @path=nil, @logger=nil, @git_system_env_variables={
            "GIT_DIR"=>nil,
            "GIT_WORK_TREE"=>nil,
            "GIT_INDEX_FILE"=>nil,
            "GIT_SSH"=>nil
        }>>, @objectish="", @contents=nil, @trees=nil, @size=nil, @sha=nil, @mode=nil, @blobs=nil>, @parents=[#<Git: :Object: :Commit:  55ecfdf44940 @base=#<Git: :Base:    @logger=nil, @working_directory=#<Git: :WorkingDirectory:   @path=" ">, @repository=#<Git: :Repository:   @path=" /.git">, @index=#<Git: :Index:   @path=" /.git/index">, @lib=#<Git: :Lib:   @git_dir=" /.git", @git_index_file=" /.git/index", @git_work_dir=" ", @path=nil, @logger=nil, @git_system_env_variables={
                "GIT_DIR"=>nil,
                "GIT_WORK_TREE"=>nil,
                "GIT_INDEX_FILE"=>nil,
                "GIT_SSH"=>nil
            }>>, @objectish="", @contents=nil, @trees=nil, @size=nil, @sha=nil, @tree=nil, @parents=nil, @author=nil, @committer=nil, @message=nil>
        ], @author=#<Git: :Author:    @name=" ", @email="", @date=>, @committer=#<Git: :Author:    @name="", @email=" ", @date=2022-05-19 23: 01: 37 +0000>, @message="Merge remote">,
        :failed=>false
    }
]
```

but when I go through the array I can't delete the commit that contains the message "Merge remote".

I am trying this:

```
a = commits_with_status.delete_if { |x| commits_with_status.include? x["Merge remote"]}
```

the array is stored in the variable commits_with_status.

But I can't delete the commit that has this message...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be like this

```
a = commits_with_status.reject { |commit| commit[:commit].message == "Merge remote" }
```

Comment: It works ! but I modified the message so I could make sure to delete everything that starts with "Merge remote".

a = commits_with_status.reject { |commit| commit[:commit].message.start_with?(*IGNORED_COMMIT_MESSAGES) } 

IGNORED_COMMIT_MESSAGES is other array of messages we need to skip 

Thanks a lot !